# How to create alias for nullable reference type

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

I'm trying to create an alias for a nullable reference type so that I can refactor something like this:

```
public void ReceiveValues(IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object?>? values)
{
}
```

into something like this:

```
using ValuesCollection = System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object?>?;

// class, etc...

public void ReceiveValues(ValuesCollection values)
{
}
```

However, the `using` statement generates the following compiler errors:

> CS1002: ; expected
> CS1031: Type expected

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Nullability is a site-specific attribute, not an attribute of the type, so it can't be aliased.

Comment: (that is, we're talking about nullable *reference types* here... nullable value types are entirely different types and can be aliased, but must be done using `System.Nullable<...>`, not using the `?` syntax)